# Vue закрыть от индексирования одну страницу с # в url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3, meta

Нужно скрыть раздел сайта `www.site-name.com/#/en/terms` от индексации поисковиками, остальные оставить доступными. Как можно это сделать и проверить результат?

Сайт на Vue3 (Options API), используется vue-router, в url присутствует #.
Пробовал плагины vue-meta, vue-head, @vueuse/head но они все не работают. Выдаёт разные типы ошибок и сайт локально вообще не запускается (yarn run dev).
В robots.txt знак # это начало комментария, поэтому не получится прописать правила для одной страницы.

В App.vue добавлен код, но не знаю будет ли он работать:

```
watch:  {
  $route: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(to, from) {
      const meta = document.querySelector('meta[name="robots"]');
      const isNoindexPage = this.$route.fullPath.includes('terms');
      const tagValue = isNoindexPage ? 'noindex' : 'all';
      meta.setAttribute("content", tagValue);
    }
  },
}
```

Какие есть варианты скрыть от индексации одну страницу и протестировать это?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать закрыть в robots.txt от индексирования двумя способами:

Disallow: */en/term

или через UTF код символа # (если у вас используется отличная от UTF кодировка, то и код может быть другой)

Disallow: /%23/en/term

Comment: К сожалению, не работает

Comment: Что именно не работает и как вы это определили ?

Comment: Изменил robots.txt так, как вы написали (оба варианта) и проверил с помощью https://technicalseo.com/tools/robots-txt/ 
Страница, которая должна была быть закрыть от индексации, была доступна, несмотря на прописанные правила

Comment: Вроде всё ок: https://tinyurl.com/2m3rxg5d. Но я бы таким сервисам не доверял, лучше проверять нативными инструментами поисковиков: https://search.google.com/search-console/index

Comment: Точнее даже вот этот url для корректности правил лучше: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool

Comment: Вы проверяете путь `http://lvo.ru/test/en/terms`, а на моём сайте он `http://lvo.ru/test/#/en/terms`. Поэтому и не работает ваш способ

Comment: test условная замена любой строки. Если проверять через гугловский инструмент и в запросе заменить # на %23 то их анализатор показывает блокировку (https://tinyurl.com/2hywhljb)

Comment: Но даже гугло анализатор может не точно показывать обработку #. Надо проверять через постановку в индексацию отдельно взятой страницы.

Comment: Путь должен остаться таким же `http://lvo.ru/test/#/en/terms`, изменить на `http://lvo.ru/test/%23/en/terms` не получится. Нужно найти способ закрыть эту страницу от индексации